# why is firebase not part of googleapis?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0

Googleapis is an exhaustive api family provided by Google.

The below three are universal python modules provided by google to help with all of the google apis and each of the api is supported with excellent documentation.

```
import apiclient
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
```

But strangely, the recently launched Firebase (infact improved) by Google, has its own set of documentation and does not align with googleapis.

Does anyone know how to use the api helpers already available with Firebase?. Any help is appreciated.

Just tried hitting the auth url, and it returns firebase. Technically, the scope is supported, but not sure how to access the methods underneath.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase 
returns
firebase
```